How to check if a particular string/property exist in JSON file using Groovy
I have below jSON file in which I need to check for 'shortTerm' and 'longTerm' existence.
If they exist take the value from the versionName and assign to shortTerm variable else assign 'N/A' if doesn't exist.
Json file
    {
  "component": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839",
  "componentName": "Apache Commons IO",
  "version": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/5425twrhjbsgjh947543734hfsdhugre8473",
  "versionName": "2.6",
  "origin": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/5425twrhjbsgjh947543734hfsdhugre8473/origins/82d1de62-fd7d-42cd-9cca-1b7d6d54cfc1",
  "originName": "2.6",
  "originExternalNamespace": "maven",
  "originExternalId": "commons-io:commons-io:2.6",
  "shortTerm": {
    "version": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/69624cfa-4d47-4dd6-bff3-deb5869d8145",
    "versionName": "2.17.0",
    "vulnerabilityRisk": {
      "critical": 0,
      "high": 0,
      "medium": 0,
      "low": 0
    },
    "origin": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/69624cfa-4d47-4dd6-bff3-deb5869d8145/origins/fbe4eb3b-31be-43de-aba5-d1362bf0cde7",
    "originName": "2.17.0",
    "originExternalNamespace": "maven",
    "originExternalId": "commons-io:commons-io:2.17.0"
  },
  "longTerm": {
    "version": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/2a972758-8f30-4e87-b111-1b21ce063ea8",
    "versionName": "20030203.000550",
    "vulnerabilityRisk": {
      "critical": 0,
      "high": 0,
      "medium": 0,
      "low": 0
    },
    "origin": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/2a972758-8f30-4e87-b111-1b21ce063ea8/origins/1142e462-02d8-4d87-b3d2-e6f8e3f03a31",
    "originName": "20030203.000550",
    "originExternalNamespace": "maven",
    "originExternalId": "commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550"
  },
  "_meta": {
    "allow": [
      "GET"
    ],
    "href": "https://bdhub.uat.com/api/components/829y58942yt8943hn8t943y89ty4389ht839/versions/5425twrhjbsgjh947543734hfsdhugre8473/origins/82d1de62-fd7d-42cd-9cca-1b7d6d54cfc1/upgrade-guidance",
    "links": []
  }
}

Groovy Code :-
def upgradeJson = readJSON file:'upgrade.json'
if (upgradeJson.containsKey('shortTerm'))
   {
     def shortTerm = upgradeJson.shortTerm.versionName
     def longTerm = upgradeJson.longTerm.versionName
   }
else
   {
     def shortTerm = "NA"
     def longTerm = "NA"
   }

Above code always gives below error:-
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: shortTerm for class:
Can someone help to fix the code.
Thanks.

You may want to provide the full exception.  It looks like the class name was cut off.  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: shortTerm for class: the next phrase should be a class name after the class:  That would be informative.  Also line numbers might help because it might be on a line not posted.

So I suspect that upgradeJson.shortTerm.versionName may have worked and that is not the line that threw the exception.  I think when you tried to refer to shortTerm variable it died.  Since Jenkins executes all of this in a closure then any variable that is not local would be resolved against the the Closure itself (which is a class) and blamo!  MissingPropertyException thrown.
The use of def within an if block will scope that variable to the block and will not be available outside it.  Therefore changing it to this should allow you to refer to shortTerm and longTerm after the if statement:
def upgradeJson = readJSON file:'upgrade.json'
def shortTerm = 'NA'
def longTerm = 'NA'
if (upgradeJson.containsKey('shortTerm'))
   {
     shortTerm = upgradeJson.shortTerm.versionName
     longTerm = upgradeJson.longTerm.versionName
   }

println( "I can refer to those variables because they are in scope: ${shortTerm} ${longTerm}")

You could even get cutesy with it by adding some Groovy syntax:
def shortTerm = upgradeJson.shortTerm?.versionName ?: "NA"
def longTerm = upgradeJson.longTerm?.versionName ?: "NA"

And viola no more if.  It's not necessary if you like the if, but just showing off Groovy's unique features.
